# How to pass Windows Form data to Base form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a question about pass parameters to base winform.

So I have a base form included save, delete and update buttons and the other forms will be inherited from this form.

The generic object is change by form type. I can do it but  How can I pass data from form to base form ?

This is the base form's code.

```
public partial class BaseForm : Form, BaseInterface
{
    public object genericItem;


    public BaseForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Add()
    {
        var a = genericItem.ToXml();

        MessageBox.Show(a);
    }

    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Update(string xml)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Add();
    }
}
```

And this is the form which inherited from Base Form

```
public partial class Definitions : BaseForm
{
    public Definitions() : base()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
}
```

When I clicked to Button 1, I need to get inherited form values. How can I do it?

Comment: if all else fails, you can always just serialize the data you are looking for and deserialize it.

Comment: how can i do it ? do you have any examples ? @mahlatse

Comment: Do you want to cast the base to a child or a child to a base? Or you cant access the parent methods or properties?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your base class to abstract with abstract method, which will have to be implemented in derived class (Note code not tested, just and example):

```
public abstract partial class BaseForm : Form, BaseInterface
{
    public object genericItem;

    public BaseForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Add()
    {
        var a = genericItem.ToXml();
        MessageBox.Show(a);
    }

    public abstract object GatherData();

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        genericItem = GatherData();
        Add();
    }
}

public partial class Definitions : BaseForm
{
    public Definitions() : base()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public override object GatherData()
    {
        return new SomeKindOfData();
    }
}
```

Comment: i solved the problem like this. created a virtual voids on base form and overrided from another from like you.

Comment: You might do that as well. But making abstract you will be forced to implement abstract method.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use an abstract class just because visual studio can't really design those (as far as I know). Instead consider using virtual properties with a throw in it in the base class, forcing anyone extending the class to implement the method. **Here's the thing**: This method is definitely the easiest up front, but probably the messiest if you plan on reusing this code a lot in the future or in a large scale environment. Below is an example of this solution.

```
public partial class BaseForm : Form, BaseInterface
{
    public object genericItem;

    // this can be overridden in extending classes
    virtual int SomeDataHere => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public BaseForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Add()
    {
        var a = genericItem.ToXml();

        MessageBox.Show(a);
    }

    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Update(string xml)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(SomeDataHere);
        Add();
    }
}
```